# Assign both menu-complete and dynamic-complete-history to TAB

Tags: bash, autocomplete, readline, inputrc

Is there a way for me to assign both menu-complete and dynamic-complete-history to <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or one to <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the other to <kbd>Tab</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>) in `.inputrc`?

I'm thinking there might be a way to setup a function and use COMPREPLY, but I can't figure out how.

What I would like to do is use 'dynamic-complete-history' for the first tab press, and if tab is pressed again use 'menu-complete'.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way

No.

Sounds like motivation for putting together
a feature patch
and a bash pull-request.